# Crystal report repeat chart on field change (a chart per deparment)

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I've a report with a chart using the data below:

```
Month N#    Month    Empl       Total       Department
9           Nov.     X          555.18      AA
9           Nov.     X          11995.58    AA
9           Nov.     Y          374.56      BB
9           Nov.     Y          619.39      BB
9           Nov.     Z          411.88      CC
9           Nov.     Z          172.52      CC
```

As far as I know Charts goes in Documents Header and it shows a chart using all the information there not taking care of which department is it.

The Chart is like this picture ( https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3389104/chart.png ) where BC, CA, NY, WA are the employees. 2000, 2001, 2002 are the months (Nov) and the Y axis is Sum(Total).

This works flawless for one Department but when I choose "All of them" only the first one is printed.

I tried making a subreport, Main report contains AA, BB and CC and the subreport the chart but I get blank pages.

Any advice?

Vb .net 3.5
Crystal Report  2010
SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a screenshot of the chart expert? It sounds like you simply need to add the department to the "on change of" list.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3389104/chart_expert.png It's in spanish but you will get the idea. "On Change Of" Month & Description (Employee) and the other is Sum of Total. It won't let me add the department to "On Change Of" but I really need to make one chart per sheet per Department. Thanks.

Comment: ahh ok- that makes a bit more sense. have you got your report grouped by department? then place the chart in the group header?

Comment: That's right. The result of the query is a datatable as shown in the post, grouped by department. Thanks.